# How to use x(), y() functions in Qt

Tags: qt, qwidget

Can someone give me an example on how to use the x(), y() functions from the QWigdet class? Are these functions use to set the position of a widgets? I try to use them in this way:

```
widget->x(100);
widget->y(100);
```

Then, I got error: no matching function for call to 'QWidget::x(int).
Any answers, thanks.

Comment: you are probably looking for `setGeometry` method: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#geometry-prop

Comment: I'd say, you should read the docs a bit better, but the window geometry stuff *is* a bit complicated and confusing. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/application-windows.html#window-geometry

Comment: Thanks for the advise. English is not my first language, but I really have to improve my English level to understand clearly the Qt document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`widget->x()` returns the x position, this is not a setter.

To set a QWidget position use `widget->move(100,100)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got it now.